# Hibernate mapping exception: One to None Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications

I am trying to do a simple message system, and i get severe hbernate errors for the mapping. here is a sample of the classes

```
@Entity    
public class SMS {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "sms_id")
    private int id;


    private Korisnik sender;


    private Korisnik receiver;

    private String text;
```

and this is the Korisnik class that is in the SMS class

```
@Entity
public class Korisnik {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_num")
    private int id;

    private String name;


    public int getNumber() {
        return id;
    }
```

How can i setup the classes so it maps it right ?

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'korisnikDaoImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.sendsms.dao.impl.KorisnikDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [com/sendsms/config/AppConfig.class]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
>   Could not determine type for: com.sendsms.model.Korisnik, at table:
>   SMS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(receiver)]

Comment: Please post your exception stack trace.

Comment: this is the root cause

Comment: You can edit your question. Add it there.

Comment: Did you add the entities in the SessionFactory <property name="annotatedClasses">?  in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@ManyToOne` to your `receiver` and `sender` fields in your `SMS` entity. If you want to specify a column, use the `@JoinColumn` annotation instead of `@Column`.

Comment: I added the @ManyToOne to the fields, now there is exception on the text field

Comment: The text field should not be a problem (except it is too short in DB).